# APNS Provide List - Which companies are Push Notification Server Providers

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

Does any one know what are the possible APNS providers around? I need to develop push notification and for that i need to **choose one like Urban Aiship or Mono Push** so i would like to have list of those providers.

Can any one help?

Please also let me know how can i send **customer specific notifications**.

Thanks,
Jigar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this isn't really a direct answer to your question, but I'd like to say that I recommend you go with Urban Airship for your push needs.

I definitely understand the desire to "comparison shop," but UA is proven and is a defacto leader in the space. With something as mission critical as push notifications, the safe money is with the biggest and most stable offering available.